# Localhost site crashes after load the 7th nested tree

Tags: mysql, tree, crash, nested, wamp

I will try to explain.

I've downloaded a site template with 6 categories as different menus on the homepage. The first is CAR, second BIKE and etc. When I click on the first it loads the properties of that category. One of that properties is a NESTED TREE as Make Model and the second property is City State that's a comum property for every category.

There is 6 NESTED TREES, one for each category. And there is another one named CITY, STATE, comum to every category. There is a total of 7 NESTED TREES.

The problem is that when I try to load the menu with the 6th nested tree it crashes after load.

When I load the menu from the first category, it loads well. The second ok. The fifth ok. But the sixth, crashes right after load.

Certainly is the Nested Tree because if I disable that 6th nested tree on MYSQL the page loads well.

Is there any sort of limitation on MYSQL? Any thoughts? I'm using WAMP.

Comment: When you say `it` crashes, `what` crashes. Is it `apache` is it `mysql` or is it the `application`. More detail please. Also what is the name of the template you downloaded?

Comment: iAuto. I don't know what crashes, I think it not crashes after all. It only loads the page and keeps loading after it was loaded and then I get Connection Reset error...